# Can I replace a div with css rounded corners with VML circle using Raphael.js library?

Tags: css, raphael

Now I've just tried Raphael library, but it seems to me that I can use it to replace elements with rounded corners to get rounded corners in Internet Explorer versions less than 9. I know there are other ways to get rounded corners in browsers that do not support them natively. But I would like to know if using SVG and VML is worth for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends from the project you are working on. If you are using `Raphael library` in other parts of your project, I do not see why you should not use rectangles with rounded corners.

For example:

```
Ext.onReady( function()
{
    var paper = Raphael(0,0,200,200),
        r     = paper.rect(30, 30, 60, 40, 10),
        t     = paper.text(60, 50, "BLAH");

    r.attr({fill: 'orange', stroke: 'brown'});
    t.attr({fill: 'browm', "font-weight": "bold"});

});
```

You can also see the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/S5BSp/11/).

Otherwise, it uses a lot of CPU resources. Unless you are going to use a few, I would not recommend.
 
**To place it on `DIV`, just use this: `var paper = Raphael("div id", 500, 500)`**

Comment: Thank you! I am using css pie library for rounded corners in ie7-8. It works fine. But not working with selectors containing :before and :after. I guess pie is using svg too and have problems with targeting on such elements (I mean pseudo classes :before and :after).

Comment: So, can I place a rectangle on pseudo-element?

Comment: if you specify your working canvas/div, then by changing rectangle's coordinates, you can position them anywhere within your specified canvas/div

Comment: Right! Didn't thought of this. Thanks again!